# OpenSSL error when creating a new Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, rvm

I'm trying to create a new Rails project using the railstutorial.org.  However, when I try to create a new app, I get the following error:

```
User-MacBook-Air:rails_projects user$ rails new first_ap
/user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': dlopen(/user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/digest/md5.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/digest/md5.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/digest/md5.bundle
    from /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /user.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /user.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /user.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /user.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /user.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.14/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /user.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /user.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

How do I get rid of this OpenSSL error?  I am using the following:

```
Rails 3.2.14
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]

rvm 1.22.11 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Comment: add results of: `file /user.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/digest/md5.bundle /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` and files `/user.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ext/digest/md5/mkmf.log` + `/user.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ext/openssl/mkmf.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't installed OpenSSL, try installing it with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
brew install openssl
```

Comment: When I try that I get the output: 

Warning: openssl-1.0.1e already installed

I'm confused as to how rails can't find openssl when I create a new app.

Comment: Try `brew reinstall openssl` and then, uninstall rvm: `rvm implode`; and reinstall rvm. Although, you might dig on [Chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) as it's wayyyy simpler for development.

Comment: this version of rvm made sure openssl is installed and ruby was compiled using it, switching to other tool will not make it working magically, there was either a conflict during compilation or something changed after ruby was compiled.

Comment: Any number of things might have happened, from rvm being difficult, to a botched homebrew installation, to your environment having both a homebrew and a macports or other OpenSSL install hanging around.

Re-installing both OpenSSL and Ruby should help :) Did that resolve your problem? If so, could you select an answer?

Answer (score 7):

Well, there's a very large chance it was overkill but for me uninstalling ruby entirely and then reinstalling it and all the gems that my project uses solved the problem.

If you're using rbenv, the commands that I used were 

`rbenv uninstall 2.6.3`

`rbenv install 2.6.3`

`gem install bundler`

`gem install rails -v 6.0.2`

`rbenv rehash`

`bundle update`

Again, this is probably overkill, but it solved the problem after `brew install openssl` didn't work for me.